# HTML Code too long

Tags: html, email, html-email, rules, transport

I have a quick question I have an HTML Signature for may emails. I need to implement them into my exchange server`s transport rules.

Unfortunately the limit is at 4096 characters and my HTML signature is 8950 Characters.

I would like to know if there is an HTML code that will access a public URL and then gets the necessary HTML content from the public URL, so that I can circumvent the limitation.

Thanks for your help

It should be normal HTML stuff i guess, Office 365 Microsoft is what I am using.
I have my company logo comming from the server, does this mean Gmail user will not be able to see my logo? I am bringing it in via a URL
every time I try to place the HTML code it shows the actual signature, any idea how i can change that?

regards

Comment: Not really (at least as far as I know), however if you post the HTML for us to see, it might be possible to achieve the same thing with less markup.

Comment: Care to show us your HTML? 8950 characters sounds like a lot for an email signature, inline styles included and all.

Comment: As @SharkofMirkwood said if you could post the HTML we might be able to reduce markup

Answer (score 1):

Its difficult to code for HTML emails as different email clients deal with html emails in different ways.
You could
1. Reduce spacing used in html tags, inline styling.
2. Modify markup so as to use lesser tags

Best would be to reduce the signature content, remove unnecessary parts.

In case you cant do, so you could use a image of your signature & link a image tag.[NOT RECOMMENDED] This wont work in gmail since it blocks image loading by default.

Maybe posting your signature might help?

Comment: I can not add the HTML code, it always changes it it into the signateur direct.